# Fancybox Gallery not working with no errors in browser

Tags: jquery, api, fancybox, gallery

I used the API Method "Open" to create a gallery on a page. This function has worked for me on other sites before but for some reason, the gallery wont pop up on other sites I am doing.

I am currently using Jquery v1.10.2 but also tested with the v 1.10.1 min.js.
Fancybox version : version: 2.1.5.

I see no errors in firebug and all other jquery functions i have on the site works perfectly. I am just a little baffled and would truly appreciate some insight as to why this is happening.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />

<!-- Add Button helper (this is optional) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>

<!-- Add Thumbnail helper (this is optional) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

<!-- Add Media helper (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>


<a id="manualPop" href="javascript:;">Gallery</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#manualPop").on('click',function() { 
        alert('Dehya');     
        $.fancybox.open([
            {
                             'href'  : 'http://images.realtyserver.com/photo_server.php?btnSubmit=GetPhoto&board=jamaica&name=000014E4.L01',
             'title' : 'Image'
                }], {
            helpers : {
                thumbs : {
                    width: 75,
                    height: 50
                }
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Can you share the code you are currently using for Fancybox that isn't working?

Comment: I found something that maybe the cause of this. The images I am loading does not have a format tag at the end but are loading through the browser. Is it possible that the upgrade of fancybox has limited the view of image to only a certain format type?

Comment: In your options add `type: "image"` see http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#support ==>FAQ tab, No. 5

Comment: The problem for me was the URL was a dynamic link to a controller action that returned an image (so the URL didn't end in ".jpg" etc). I think fancybox uses this to determine whether the URL is for an image. Either way, setting `type: "image"` fixed it for me